# Is it possible to create a django query that finds the latest unique dates across two models?

Tags: python, django

I've got two models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    active_date = DateField()
    # A bunch of other fields

class ModelB(models.Model):
    active_date = DateField()
    # A bunch of other fields
```

What I need is an ordered list of `active_date` values in *either* table.  Additionally, I need to be able to page this list (e.g.- grab [0:10] or [10:20]).  The list will get quite long, thus I'd like to be able to do it all in a query.  Currently I am getting my dates like:

```
a_dates = ModelA.objects.all().order_by('-active_date').distinct('active_date').values('active_date')
b_dates = ModelB.objects.all().order_by('-active_date').distinct('active_date').values('active_date')
dates_list = merge_dates(a_dates, b_dates) # function merges lists, drops duplicates, and puts in descending order
return dates_list[start:end]
```

Obviously when my number of entities gets large, and that date list gets large, this will become slower.  Any thoughts on a better way to do this?

Comment: You can perform a `.union(..)`, so `dates_list = a_dates.union(b_dates)`.

Comment: That looks perfect (and I had no idea it existed, thanks!).  So to verify, `.union()` is all done by the db?  so something like `a_dates.union(b_dates)[10:20]` will efficiently do the paging I need to do?

Comment: yes, `.union` is done at the database.